# How to insert a parameter when opening a new window in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I want to have a Blazor component that has a particular state.  Upon an interaction, a new window should open, and a parameter should be introduced to the new window and component.

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;

<input type="text" @bind-value=SomeWords />

<input type="button"  value="Change" @onclick="@(async () => await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<Counter>("open", "/"))" />

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string SomeWords {get; set;}

    public void Changeword()
        {
        SomeWords = "The New Page";
        }
}
```

then using it:

```
<Counter SomeWords="First Page"></Counter>
```

So when the app opens, it says, "First Page."  When clicking on the button, a new window of the same page should open up with the words "The New Page," with the old page still having the words, "First Page."  I would like to do this in WebAssembly, but if not possible, as solution in Server would still be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I have a totally different problem from the asked question but anybody can help with it? In my WinForms application, I am calling a popup window using a function. the popup property is set to TopMost = true, TopLevel = true, when I call this popup from the method it works fine. but if I make that method async then the popup will no longer on the top. my code :  [https://del.dog/TopMost_withAsync](https://del.dog/TopMost_withAsync.txt) help please.

Comment: Hi.  Can you please make this a separate question?  You are more likely going to get a response that way.

Comment: because of my reputation level I am not able to post questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use several route for a page

```
@page "/"
@page "/{title}"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;

<input type="text" @bind-value=SomeWords />

<input type="button" value="Change" @onclick="@(async () => await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<Counter>("open", $"/{SomeWords}"))" />

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string SomeWords { get; set; } = "First Page";

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            SomeWords = title;
    }
}
```